# Google Sheets formula to find rows with matching values, looking up in multiple columns

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

What would be the Google Sheets formula to search for a matching value in a range that goes across multiple rows an columns? For example I need to search the entire range H:P (all rows and columns) and find the cells with a matching value, if any. Ultimately in this case I need just a list of the row numbers where a matching cell is found. In the screenshot there are two matches highlighted in green. There is a match on O2, and on M3. So in this case I need a result like "2,3".

I have tried various things for several hours with no luck. Most examples of formulas that I could find and understand are about looking up in either a single column, or row.

Any help appreciated! Thank you!

[image: range to be searched]

Comment: Welcome. Would you please advise how much data do you have (how many rows and columns). Would you please also advise, is this a one-off exercise, or something that is to be repeated (and if so, how often).

Comment: _There is a match on O2, and on M3. So in this case I need a result like "2,3"_ Would you please explain where is this result to be recorded. If there was a match in Cell L3 and Cell N2, the result would also be "2,3" - Would you please explain how you would distinguish between these two identical results. Would you also clarify whether it is possible that the same code exists more than twice  - that is, there might be three cells containing the same text.

Comment: Hi @Tedinoz, so sorry I see this just now. I expected I would get an email if anyone comments, but I had to return to the website to see this!

Comment: There could be only a single match per row, always. In my real data sheet the range I need to search is 9 columns and about 50 rows, but the rows can grow. Can't share the real thing, but I am trying to put together an example spreadsheet. And will post in a bit.

Comment: Regarding receiving emails when there are answers, comments and so on. Click on your Profile, Click on "Edit profile and settings". A menu list opens on the left of the screen. Under "Email settings", click on "Edit email settings". The options of the right-hand side of the screen will change. Under "Inbox", choose the email frequency that you want. I can't promise that this works each and every time cause I don't think I get over-whelmed by emails  from StackExchange; however, I understand that this is the relevant setting.

Comment: Thanks so much @Tedinoz! I will check the email settings! In case you are still willing to take a look at this, I created an example document of what I am trying to do exactly. Including what I have tried already, and what I want to achieve. As someone that doesn't completely grasp spreadsheet formulas, it is likely that I am overcomplicating things altogether on how to handle the task at hand. I hope it all makes sense... https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PFb4C9yTN8bSUmUvgj1_I2o2TgpxKS_1Mn8T_LAdYJg/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this formula in cell D16 and copy down to cells D17 and D18.

---

```
=join(", ",
sort(
query(
{
  InStock!$C$2:$C,InStock!$B$2:$B;
  InStock!$D$2:$D,InStock!$B$2:$B;
  InStock!$E$2:$E,InStock!$B$2:$B;
  InStock!$F$2:$F,InStock!$B$2:$B;
  InStock!$G$2:$G,InStock!$B$2:$B;
  InStock!$H$2:$H,InStock!$B$2:$B;
  InStock!$I$2:$I,InStock!$B$2:$B;
  InStock!$J$2:$J,InStock!$B$2:$B;
  InStock!$K$2:$K,InStock!$B$2:$B
},
"select Col2 where Col1 = '"&C17&"'"))
)
```

---

It is not clear from the question whether the formula is to be used in a single cell, or in several cells (as in the example).

The queried ranges are open-ended (e.g. `InStock!$C$2:$C,InStock!$B$2:$B;`) - this allows additional data rows to be added to sheet="InStock" and that data will be included in the query.

---

**Example Output**

[image: Example output]

Comment: Amazing! THANK YOU so much @Tedinoz ! Works like magic, exactly what I needed!